# How to add a rich Textbox (HTML) to a table cell?

Tags: pdf, itext, richtext

I have a rich text box named:”DocumentContent” which I’m going to add its content to pdf using the below code:

```
iTextSharp.text.Font font = FontFactory.GetFont(@"C:\Windows\Fonts\arial.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED, 12f, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK);
            DocumentContent = System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(DocumentContent);
            Chunk chunkContent = new Chunk(DocumentContent);
            chunkContent.Font = font;            

            Phrase PhraseContent = new Phrase(chunkContent);
            PhraseContent.Font = font;


            PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
            table.WidthPercentage = 100;
            PdfPCell cell;

            cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(PhraseContent));
            cell.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
            table.AddCell(cell);
```

The problem is when I open PDF file the content appears as HTML not a text as below:

```
<p>Overview&#160; line1 </p><p>Overview&#160; line2
</p><p>Overview&#160; line3 </p><p>Overview&#160;
line4</p><p>Overview&#160; line4</p><p>Overview&#160;
line5&#160;</p>
```

But it should look like below

```
Overview line1
Overview line2
Overview line3
Overview line4
Overview line4
Overview line5
```

What I'm going to do is to keep all the styling which user apply to the rich text and just change font family to Arial.

I can change Font Family but I need to Decode this content from HTML to Text.

Could you please advise?
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please take a look at the [HtmlContentForCell](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/htmlworker/HtmlContentForCell) example.

In this example, we have the HTML you mention:

```
public static final String HTML = "<p>Overview&#160;line1</p>"
        + "<p>Overview&#160;line2</p><p>Overview&#160;line3</p>"
        + "<p>Overview&#160;line4</p><p>Overview&#160;line4</p>"
        + "<p>Overview&#160;line5&#160;</p>";
```

We also create a font for the `<p>` tag:

```
public static final String CSS = "p { font-family: Cardo; }";
```

In your case, you may want to replace `Cardo` with `Arial`.

Note that we registered the regular version of the `Cardo` font:

```
FontFactory.register("resources/fonts/Cardo-Regular.ttf");
```

If you need bold, italic and bold-italic, you also need to register those fonts of the same `Cardo` family. (In case of arial, you'd register arial.ttf, arialbd.ttf, ariali.ttf and arialbi.ttf).

Now we can parse this HTML and CSS into a list of `Element` objects with the `parseToElementList()` method. We can use these objects inside a cell:

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
table.addCell("Some rich text:");
PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();
for (Element e : XMLWorkerHelper.parseToElementList(HTML, CSS)) {
    cell.addElement(e);
}
table.addCell(cell);
document.add(table);
```

See [html_in_cell.pdf](http://itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/html_in_cell.pdf) for the resulting PDF.

I do not have the time/skills to provide this example in iTextSharp, but it should be very easy to port this to C#.

Comment: Thanks Bruno,This is very helpful. I appreciate your help. Now I'm trying to change it to C#.

Comment: OK, it would be great if you could add the C# version of my code as an extra answer once you've ported the example.

Answer (score 4):

Finally I write this code in c# which is working perfectly, Thanks to Bruno who helped me to understand XMLWorker.

Here is an example using XMLWorker in C#.

I used a sample HTML as below:

```
public static string HTML = "<p>Overview&#160;line1âââŵẅẃŷûâàêÿýỳîïíìôöóòêëéèẁẃẅŵùúúüûàáäâ</p>"
            + "<p>Overview&#160;line2</p><p>Overview&#160;line3</p>"
            + "<p>Overview&#160;line4</p><p>Overview&#160;line4</p>"
            + "<p>Overview&#160;line5&#160;</p>";
```

I have created Test.css file and saved it in SharePoint Style Library. (for this test I saved it in D drive to keep it simple) 
Here is the content of my test css file:
    p { font-family: arial; }

Then using the below c# code I saved the PDF file in D drive. ( In SharePoint I used Memorystream. I keep this example very simple to understand )

```
string fileName = @"D:\Test.pdf";                     
var css = @"D:\Test.css";
using (var ActionStream = new MemoryStream(UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(HTML)))
{
    using (FileStream cssFile = new FileStream(css, FileMode.Open))
    {
        var document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 30, 30, 10, 10);                    
        var worker = XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance();
        var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create));
        document.Open();
        worker.ParseXHtml(writer, document, ActionStream, cssFile);
        writer.CloseStream = false;
        document.Close();

    }
}
```

It creates Test.pdf file adding my HTML with Font Family:Arial. So all of the Welsh Characters can be saved in PDF file.

Note: I have added iTextSharp.dll  v:5.5.3  and XMLworker.dll v: 5.5.3 to my project.

```
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.html;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using iTextSharp.tool.xml;
using iTextSharp.tool.xml.css;
using iTextSharp.tool.xml.html;
using iTextSharp.tool.xml.parser;
using iTextSharp.tool.xml.pipeline;
```

Hope this can be useful.

Kate