# Line changes to a string from html

Tags: java, html, parsing, pdf, itext

I have to create a pdf by using itextpdf api. I also have jsoup api in the project. I've managed to create a pdf meeting all the requirements for it except one thing. One column of cells in the pdf have to get their content text from the web-application UI from html-content. So, I get all the tags and all with them to the pdf. Like this:

[image]

Now I found a way to get rid of the tags by using Jsoup.parse(cellContentText).text();

However, there's no line changes or anything now. Would it be possible to get some of the html formatting to show in the pdf? If so, how?

Comment: It's a rather nasty workaround, but maybe you should consider running over the text/input before the Jsoup.parse activity, replace <li> and/or <br> tags with something else (special character or alike), and then, after Jsoup.parse - use that "something" to insert line break into your PDF.

Comment: Please read the chapter "Parsing XML and XHTML" from the free ebook [The Best iText Questions on StackOverflow](http://pages.itextpdf.com/ebook-stackoverflow-questions.html). You have some HTML snippets and you want to convert these snippets into iText objects such as `Paragraph`, `List`, etc. If so, your question is a duplicate of [Add a rich Textbox to PDF using iTextSharp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27015644/add-a-rich-textbox-to-pdf-using-itextsharp) where we use XML Worker to parse an HTML snippet and some CSS into an `ElementList`.

Comment: Thanks a ton! Actually your HtmlContentForCell-example was perfect for me. Yesterday I went through examples that didn't quite fit my situation. http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/htmlworker/HtmlContentForCell

Comment: @BrunoLowagie Well, actually I followed that example which seemed exactly to solve my problem but in the for loop for parsing the html snippet to element list I bumped into an exception: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28871767/nonewlineparagraph-cannot-be-cast-to-element

Comment: @BrunoLowagie Nevermind, I managed to solve that problem and ALL the different problems related to XMLWorker, by **updating the itextpdf and xmlworker to be the exact same version. ** This should be stressed somewhere :)

Answer (score 1):

I dont know the Jsoup API from my head, but maybe something like

```
List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
for(Element e: Jsoup.parse(html).findAll('li')){
  lines.add(e.text())
}
```

And then add the lines of text to the pdf one by one.