# link coming twice while exporting to pdf using itextsharp

Tags: pdf, gridview, itext

my asp boundfield:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField = "SiteUrl" HtmlEncode="false" HeaderText = "Team Site URL" SortExpression = "SiteUrl" ></asp:BoundField>
```

My itextsharpcode

```
for (int i = 0; i < dtUIExport.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < dtUIExport.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                if (j == 1)
                { continue; }

                    string cellText = Server.HtmlDecode(dtUIExport.Rows[i][j].ToString());
                    //  cellText = Server.HtmlDecode((domainGridview.Rows[i][j].FindControl("link") as HyperLink).NavigateUrl);
                    // string cellText = Server.HtmlDecode((domainGridview.Rows[i].Cells[j].FindControl("hyperLinkId") as HyperLink).NavigateUrl);
                    iTextSharp.text.Font font = new iTextSharp.text.Font(bf, 10, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL);
                    font.Color = new BaseColor(domainGridview.RowStyle.ForeColor);
                    iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPCell cell = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPCell(new Phrase(12, cellText, font));

                    pdfTable.AddCell(cell);
            }
        }
```

domainGridview is the grid name. However I am manipulating the pdf using data table.
The hyperlink is coming in this way

**http://dtsp2010vm:47707/sites/TS1>http://dtsp2010vm:47707/sites/TS1**

How to rip the addtional link?
Edit: i have added the screenshot of pdf file[image]

Comment: Can you show use the value of `cellText`? There is no reason why iText would duplicate text, hence the problem is probably caused by the fact that the text occurs twice in the `cellText` string.

Comment: (Thanks Bruno! at last someone took notice of the question, and that too the owner of the itextsharp! I feel Privilidged. thanks Again.) cellText is beng passed as a parameter while creating new pdf cell. in this line:  iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPCell cell = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPCell(new Phrase(12, cellText, font)); Also the duplicacy is observed only in hyperlink column. i have sevral other column where the texts renders just fine.

Comment: The screen shot makes it clear that you are adding an HTML string to a `PDFCell`. You shouldn't be surprised that this HTML string is added literally: you aren't parsing the HTML into an iText object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initial question didn't get an answer because it is rather misleading. You claim *link coming twice*, but that's not true. From the point of view, the link is shown as HTML syntax:

```
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com">http://stackoverflow.com</a>
```

This is the HTML definition of *a single link* that is stored in the `cellText` parameter.

You are adding this content to a `PdfPCell` as if it were a simple `string`. It shouldn't surprise you that iText renders this `string` as-is. It would be a serious bug if iText didn't show:

```
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com">http://stackoverflow.com</a>
```

If you want the HTML to be rendered, for instance like this: http://stackoverflow.com, you need to parse the HTML into iText objects (e.g. the `<a>`-tag will result in a `Chunk` object with an anchor).

Parsing HTML for use in a `PdfPCell` is explained in the following question: [How to add a rich Textbox (HTML) to a table cell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27015644/add-a-rich-textbox-to-pdf-using-itextsharp)

When you have `<a href="http"//stackoverflow.com">http://stackoverflow.com</a>`, you are talking about HTML, not just ordinary text. There's a big difference.

Comment: Thanks Bruno for making me understand the flaw in my understanding. I parsed the html of cellText and it worked

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this code for achiveing my result. Thanks Bruno for your answer

```
for (int j = 0; j < dtUIExport.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                if (j == 1)
                { continue; }
                if (j == 2)
                {
                    String cellTextLink = Server.HtmlDecode(dtUIExport.Rows[i][j].ToString());
                    cellTextLink = Regex.Replace(cellTextLink, @"<[^>]*>", String.Empty);                        
                    iTextSharp.text.Font fontLink = new iTextSharp.text.Font(bf, 10, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL);
                    fontLink.Color = new BaseColor(domainGridview.RowStyle.ForeColor);
                    iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPCell cellLink = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPCell(new Phrase(12, cellTextLink, fontLink));

                    pdfTable.AddCell(cellLink);
                }
```